# iOS Distribution Certificate for iOS Developer University Program account

Tags: ios, testflight

I am struggling with trying to release an app on TestFlight under an iOS Developer University Program account. I have googled only to come across questions where the option for creating a certificate for 'App Store and Ad Hoc' is greyed out. My problem differs in that the option does not appear at all under the production certificates list:

[image: iOS Developer University Program new certificate]

When I log in to my normal account for distributing iOS apps on my own, the normal options appear: 
[image: Apple Dev Program new certificate]

Why are these options unavailable in my iOS Developer University Program account? I have tried to have the owner also login and the options are still unavailable. When I try to run Product --> Archive to upload to TestFlight I get an error of course, saying 'Your account does not have permission to create iOS distribution certificates'.

I am really not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For TestFlight use Ad Hoc option

Comment: As the error message says, Developer University accounts do not have access to test flight or ad-hoc distribution.  Other members of the same developer university team can install your app using the developer signed IPA since they will have access to your team's profiles